# How to get value in Advance custom field pro option page

Tags: wordpress

I create a new Theme option page using ACF- Pro and i want to get field value in Header.php but it is not showing any value

```
 <?php the_field('call_now'); ?>
```

I am using the_field to get the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value from option page you need to use option with your field name

```
<?php the_field('call_now', 'option'); ?>
```